# How to solve this nonlinear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the nonlinear ordinary differential equation of the form $$r((y_t)^2+(x_t)^2)=g(r^2-y^2-x^2)$$
where $r$ and $g$ are constants and $y_t$ and $x_t$ represent first order derivatives of y and x with respect to t?

I know that this is the differential equation for a hypocycloid and that the general solution for this is the parametric system of the form
$$\begin{cases}
x(t)=a\cos t+b\cos ct\\
y(t)=a\sin t-b\sin ct\\
\end{cases}$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants, but I don't know how to get from the differential equation to this solution.

Thank you in advance for any idea or proposed solution, I've been struggling for a month straight with this.

Comment: Isn't this separable?

Comment: There is information missing. For any solution to this equation you could add a variation to $y$ and get a solution for $x$ by solving the equation with $y$ as parameter.